# How heating a substance makes electrons fall into lower orbits and emit light

Tags: thermodynamics, electrons, radiation

When heat is given to a substance, the electrons should get energy and fly out  creating light. But instead the electrons fall into lower orbit and emit radiation. Please explain.

Comment: Please read this article, it explains a lot  http://science.howstuffworks.com/light7.htm

Answer (score 2):

Energy from heat makes an electron jump to a higher orbit, when it falls back to its original orbit, it emits radiation, and if it is in the range of visible light you see it.

Comment: Does this explanation applies for incandescent bulb where electrical energy is  converted into heat energy in the wire filament. The electrons on the filament  absorbs heat energy and goes to higher orbit and later come back to lower orbit and thereby generating radiation in the range of visible light

Comment: yes, it applies to everything, a bulb filament , a piece of wood/coal/steel etc it is the same process.